# Association where client orders from products. How to setup relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm fiddling with rails and trying to build a small app for practicing purposes:

I want a client to order one or more products

I have a `client` table, a `product` table and last an `order` table which has a `client_id` and `product_id`

Now, I'm not quite sure how to set up a good relation between these table as in: client goes to product page, chooses product and saves the order.

Any help about which model should have which relation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up associations like this

```
Class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :orders
has_many :products,through: :orders 

end

Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :orders
has_many :clients,through: :orders

end

Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :client
belongs_to :product

end
```

For more details,see these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)**

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it would have been because a lack of context in the answer

Comment: @RichPeck I hope i've given enough context regarding the OP is just asking for association set up!

Comment: I haven't downvoted but I guess the association is wrong here, `through` is used at wrong place. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Product and Client have direct relation with Order, using `through` with them doesn't make sense

Comment: @RSB You are right! I cant think how i missed.Thanks and you got my upvote :)

Comment: Glad to help, now its right, the downvote should be removed now

Answer (score 1):

The association should look something like this

```
Class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders
  has_many :products,through: :orders

end

Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders
  has_many :clients,through: :orders

end

Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :product

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
#app/models/product.rb
has_many :orders
has_many :clients, through: :orders

#app/models/order.rb
belongs_to :client

has_many :order_products
has_many :products, through: :order_products

#app/models/client.rb
has_many :orders 
has_many :products, through: :orders
```

The way to handle the creation of a new `order` is to set a [`uuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for it, and then create another join model which will handle order products. You could do this with the `order` model, but I felt it best to describe the basic way, as it will give you something to work from

--

[**uuid**](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom)

We like to set `uuid` columns for sensitive data like orders:

```
#migration
add_column :orders, :uuid, :varchar, after: :id

#app/models/order.rb
before_create :set_uuid

private

def set_uuid
   unless self.uuid
       loop do
           token = SecureRandom.hex(5)
           break token unless self.class.exists?(uuid: token)
       end
   end
end
```

This means every order will have as many products as you want, accessible like this:

```
@user.orders.first.products #-> returns order products
```

--

Edit - just saw `@Pavan's` answer. Sorry if it's the same - hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You have two approaches

1) set has_and_belongs_to_many between client and product model.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

2) set through relation between the client and production through using keyword through

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  ha_smany :products, through: orders
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  ha_smany :clients, through: orders
end
```

I am suggesting you to go with second option since you have an intermediate model.

Comment: Apart from the typo's i'm not getting the answer(Where's the order model?!)